# Render a PDF using Javascript from an Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pdf

I have a very simple problem but unfortunately could not find a solution to it. I noticed on Stack Overflow there are many similar issues but none of them matches my problem completely.

I have an api server built on node and hapi which returns me a generated pdf file:

```
reply.file("./" + cfg.docRawFolder + "/" + doc._id + ".pdf");
```

This works fine.
Now I have a web server also on hapi and would like to contact the pdf endpoint on the api server using jquery and ajax:

```
$.ajax({
          url: url,
          crossDomain: true,
          type:"GET",
          headers: {
            'Authorization': token1,
            'userid': userid,
            'deviceuid': deviceuid
          }
         }).done(function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                  // some magic
         }).fail(function(err) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(err));
        });
```

The furthest I came is to get the returned garbage:

```
%PDF-1.5 %���� 1 0 obj <> endobj 2 0 obj <> endobj 3 0 obj <>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI] >>/MediaBox[ 0 0 595.32 841.92] /Contents 4 0 R/Group<>/Tabs/S>> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream x�s ���w3T04��30SI��2T0BCs=#3K=#��\^.�t�����TY��X������ 4�)����B��Yo���P{L̍��M�jC�s+�p� t��1�zd�C)� endstream endobj 5 0 obj <> endobj 6 0 obj <> endobj 7 0 obj <> endobj 8 0 obj [ 226 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 487 0 0 0 0 0 468 0 0 0 0 0 0 479 525 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 230 799 525 527 0 0 0 391 0 0 0 715 0 453] endobj 9 0 obj <> stream x��}x�U��9�;-S2%3�$�df2�$�� �C%�jB �)��bY{Y���2@����������� ۪�H��~�gm��ww�����I���������3��c.�hؤʺ1�����l&�u=c)oW�WN�6����5�1� ...
```

displayed in the same window using:

```
document.open();
document.write(data);
document.close();
```

or popup by adding this to the ajax call:

```
dataType: "application/pdf"
```

Regardless what I do I always get this garbage displayed.

What I don't want to do:

1. Expose pdfs as links on the api server
2. Create a route on the web server to download and store the pdf from
   the api server and expose a link.

What I have to do:

1. For the GET request pass 3 custom headers: the userid, deviceuid and
   Authorization, so I have to use ajax, no forms or iframes.

Ideally what I would like to achieve:

1. Display the pdf stream as a document in a lightbox or just dislpay it
   no matter how, but not in garbage format. I know the returned
   garbage works fine as I can display the pdf correctly on Android.

Many thanks in advance
Z

Comment: I don't think you can do that with AJAX. What you can do, however, is redirect the client to the URL that gives them the desired PDF.

Comment: You cannot display a binary file as text output without getting possible errors.  The text is expecting Unicode (2 bytes per character), and it gets messed up.

Answer (score 0):

If you can do stuff on the server, you could write a method which would accept the headers as query string values, and then call send a request with those headers set to the api that you have, and send the response back to the client.

Then, on the client, instead of using $.ajax, you can simply redirect to the method which accepts the query string parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Check out JavaScript blobs. You can make them fairly easily using [`Blob()`](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/06/Don-t-Build-Blobs-Construct-Them) like so:

```
var dataBlob;
var data = [];
function onReceived(data_gotten) { //Whatever your receive callback is
    data.push(data_gotten);
    dataBlob = new Blob(data);
    var obj = document.createElement('object');
    obj.setAttribute('data', dataBlob);
    obj.setAttribute('type', 'application/pdf');
    document.body.appendChild(obj);
}
```

Note: I have NOT tested this, and the code probably will not work. This is more of a theoretical way to use blobs in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but when I contact the api server pdf endpoint with my web server endpoint and "forward" the reply.file(path_to_pdf) route from the api server as a reply(data.data) on the web server and in javascript I just do a window.open(web_forwarding_endpoint) I again get garbage.
But when I remove the header requirements on the api server and do the same window.open(api_pdf_endpoint) I get a valid pdf rendered.
So the issue must be somewhere with my web endpoint forwarding the api endpoint response:
(using restling for rest):

```
rest.get( api_pdf_endpoint_url , { headers: { 'Authorization': token1, 'userid': userid, 'deviceuid': deviceuid }
} ).then(
    function(data)
    {
        fs.writeFile("./public/pdf/" + request.params.documentid + ".pdf", data.data, function(err) // This writes an empty pdf file
        {
            if(err)
            {
                console.log(err);
            }

            else
            {
                reply({message: "OK"}).code(200); 
            }
        });

        //reply(data.data); This generates garbage
    },

    function(error)
    {
        console.log(error.error);
    }
);
```

When I write the response to a file I get a valid but empty pdf generated. When I reply the response I get garbage on the web.
Perhaps I do not handle the response from the api server correctly reply.file(path_to_pdf) and am unable to write it to a correct pdf file on the web server or display it.